# Get image src from java file android

Tags: android

I have an imageButton :

```
img = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.image3);
```

I wanted to check if this img has a specific image , if yes then it changes to another image.

How can I  get and store the image resource and later can be used to compare with the current image source?

this is da code :

```
ImageButton img = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.image3);
int resource = img.getResources().getInteger(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off);

if(resource==android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off)
{
    img.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
}
```

Doesn't seem to be working
Any other way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10726519/1051147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myImageButton.setTag(R.drawable.currentImage);    //set this along when you set your image source

int drawableId = (Integer)myImageButton.getTag(); //get the resource
```