# How to get id of drawable of an imageview?

Tags: android, android-drawable

What I want to do is to get the decimal value of the image resource of an imageview on click.

Example is that a Toast should display "2130837504" which is the id of a drawable.

Comment: have you try to get id using imageview.getId()? or want something else??

Comment: Not the id of the ImageView but the current drawable of it after using setimageresource.

Comment: you can't do that. the id is only used until the resource is obtained from its id.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. What you can do is this:

> There is no getDrawableId function so you'll need to do something like
>   set a tag for the ImageView when you change its drawable. For
>   instance, set the drawable id as a tag for the ImageView so you could
>   just get the drawable id from the tag.
>
> How to do that?
>
> ```
> myImageView.setTag(R.drawable.currentImage);    //When you change the drawable
> int drawableId = (Integer)myImageView.getTag(); //When you fetch the drawable id
> ```

which is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726519/how-to-get-the-source-of-imageview-in-order-to-change-it#answer-10726558)